# Sigma-algebra associated to a stopping time.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

I was interested to understand the interpretation of the sigma field associated to a stopping time.
Let $(X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a stochastic process and  $(F_n)_{n \ge 1}$ its corresponding filtration.
Let $T$ be a stopping time. the associated sigma-algebra is $F_T = \{A \vert A\cap \{T=n\} \in F_n\}$.
I read about this in [many](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2445077/intuition-regarding-the-sigma-algebra-of-the-past-stopping-times) [many](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401241/verifying-the-interpretation-of-stopping-times-and-stopping-time-sigma-algebr) [many](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641302/sigma-algebra-of-a-stopping-time) but I still can't really understand the interpretation. Is it as following? of $F_T$ is as following : if the stopping time has occured at time $n$, i.e. $\{T=n \}$ is realized, then $A \in F_T \iff A \in F_n$. But I can't see step by step why we have this from the definition...

Comment: There is no way to make this rigorous, as far as I can see. Note that $F_n$ and $F_T$ are deterministic objects. You say "if the stopping time has occured at time $n$, [...], then $A \in \mathcal{F}_T \iff A \in \mathcal{F}_n$" but this doesn't work since the information on the occurence of the stopping time is not (and cannot be) included in the equivalence $A \in F_T \iff A \in F_n$. We cannot consider the statement "$A \in F_T \iff A \in F_n$" for fixed $\omega$ or something like this.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3131221/36150) is also a related question (one of the many).

Comment: @saz, so is it just an implication in one direction? or what is it?

Comment: Neither of them. $A \in F_T$ does not imply $A \in F_n$ and also the other direction is wrong. It **does** hold that $A \cap \{T=n\} \in F_n$ for any $A \in F_T$ but that's nothing than the very definition of $F_T$